What are the APIs related to always-on display notifications?？
I am currently using an OnePlus Ace2V phone. To my knowledge, most Android devices come with an always-on display feature like this image, which is quite convenient. However, there's one issue I'm facing: I can't seem to control this notification feature independently (for instance, I'd like to keep text message notifications in the notification bar but not have them appear on the always-on display. My only option currently is to completely turn off notifications, without the ability to manage them separately). Therefore, I'm interested in learning about the API that controls always-on display notifications so that I can perform hook operations. Is there anyone who can assist me with this?

I don't think this is possible without root, or some framework like Xposed

@gtxtreme yes，I have already rooted my device

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
